# How do I get Azure Pipeline to set Build.SourceBranch to do the tag

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I do `npm version patch && git push` I want it to run a step based on a condition.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  tags:
    include:
      - '*'
...
steps:
  - bash: |
      npm publish
    displayName: 'npm publish'
    condition: startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/')
```

But I always get `refs/heads/master` for source branch.

UPDATE:

`git push` does not normally push tags by default.

`git push --tags` or `git push --follow-tags` will push the necessary tags.  To ensure that this occurs by default

```
git config --global push.followtags true
```

**However**, this does not fully work either, because if you push master with tag the `refs/heads/master` still becomes `Build.SourceBranch`

So I have to push the tag specifically and ensure that the build triggers, but I'd rather avoid that.

I'd also like to avoid creating a separate pipeline with a different trigger (namely the tags) to do the build.

Answer (score 1):

From the YAML [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pipeline-resource), it seems like that is only used for manual or scheduled builds, not a CI trigger.

> tags: [ string ] # list of tags required on the pipeline to pickup
> default artifacts, optional; **Used only for manual or scheduled
> triggers**

I imagine you would only get it if you were doing something like the below to manually run a tag:

[image]

For most my cases specifically, I let the CI build run have a step that manages the tag creation rather than pushing a new tag.